# jQuery AJAX form using mail() PHP script sends sometimes email, and the POST data from HTML is white

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

I'm tryng to use the ajax script for my email sender form, but i can't solve the problem. Sometimes, the server didn't send the email, and whet it does it, the body of the email is clean... The message does't appear and i don't know why, the sender is my server not my test email... Can somebody help me?

This are my codes:

HTML

```
<div class="span8 module_cont module_feedback_form module_small_padding1">
    <form name="feedback_form" method="post" class="feedback_form">
        <input type="text" name="field-name" value="Nome" title="Name" class="field-name form_field">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="text" name="field-email" value="Email" title="Email" class="field-email form_field">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="text" name="field-subject" value="Oggetto" title="Subject" class="field-subject form_field">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <textarea name="field-message" cols="45" rows="5" title="Message" class="field-message form_field">Messaggio</textarea>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset2" value="Cancella" class="feedback_reset">
        <input type="button" name="submit" class="feedback_go" id="submit2" value="Invia Messaggio!">
        <div class="ajaxanswer"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
    jQuery('.feedback_go').click(function(){
    var par = jQuery(this).parents(".feedback_form");
    var name = par.find(".field-name").val();
    var email = par.find(".field-email").val();
    var message = par.find(".field-message").val();
    var subject = par.find(".field-subject").val();
    if (email.indexOf('@') < 0) {           
    email = "mail_error";
    }
    if (email.indexOf('.') < 0) {           
        email = "mail_error";
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: name, email: email, message: message, subject: subject },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('.ajaxanswer').hide().empty().html(data).show("slow");
            setTimeout("jQuery('.ajaxanswer').fadeOut('slow')",5000);
      }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$name = $_POST['field-name'];
$email = $_POST['field-email'];
$subject = $_POST['field-subject'];
$message = $_POST['field-message'];

//send email
mail("info@targetmail.com", "Information From Examplesite.com" .$email, $message);
```

}
    ?>

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also html5 input type='email' to perform simple browser validaion of the address given ( just checks conforms to email standards  and for an @ and .)

Comment: I will do that, but before i need to make the scripts to work... By now, my email arrives, but from "site admin email (es. postmaster@betasite.com) not form "email field", and also, the email arrives without text writed in the comment field...

Comment: Try this example code to change the from email address '<?php
$to      = 'info@targetmail.com';
$subject = 'Information From Examplesite.com';
$message = $email;
$headers = 'From: webmaster@yourdot.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: webmaster@yourdot.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>'. There is a setting in  php.ini if the above doesn't work. Here's the php.ini 'default is "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

change to "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f sender@mydomain.tld"'.

Comment: P.S MAKE SURE TO USE htmlspecialchars() on the user input, ie . $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['field-name']); to prevent hacking.

Comment: Little by little... ;) Where i've to put the code? By now i've 3 main files: contacts.html (here is my page structure), mail.php (here my php code) and core_site.js (all my js script). Whta i've to change.... Sorry and thank you!

Comment: I don't know where i've to put the code that you wrote... Can you be more precise please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I should warn against using this script in the real-world as it's open to abuse by would be spammers.

This said I believe the issue is that your ajax is renaming the fields as just name, email, message, subject without the field- prefix.

Comment: Ok, for the spammers, i can add the recapcha form, but how i can mod my scripts? I don't understand you...

Comment: Same as before... I've modified the ajax script like this:    data: { name: field-name, email: field-email, message: field-message, subject: field-subject },
But i've the same results... my email arrives, but from "site admin email (es. postmaster@betasite.com) not form "email field", and also, the email arrives without text writed in the comment field...